# Create link in iFrame

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I need to change the text of an element in an iFrame into a link, with a different display text. I do not have access to the HTML.

Below, where it says ThisIsAWebsiteURL.com, I need it to be a link to that website, and change the text to "Click here"

Is this possible?

```
<div class="classes" data-field="datafieldID">
    <div class="c-editor">
        <div class="c-content"> **ThisIsAWebsiteURL.com**
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-validation" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you loading an external url on the `iFrame` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A possible way would be to store that text and appending `<a href>` after the iframe has loaded:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#iframe').ready(function(){
    var link = $('.c-content').text();
    var url = ''+link+'';
    $('div').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+"Click Here"+'</a>');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classes" data-field="datafieldID">
    <iframe>

    <div class="c-editor">
        <div class="c-content">**ThisIsAWebsiteURL.com**
        </div>
    </div>
    </iframe>
    <div class="c-validation" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer is not usefull cause, anyway you cannot manipulate the content of an iframe

Comment: yes you can, after the iframe has loaded. Once you have the DOM available, You can change the DOM using jQuery if you know the id/class of the div that you want to change. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well, @Kevin Wasie is saying that he does not have access to the iframe html, i am assuming that he is loading an external url, So the content of the iframe is not defined on the root html, Meaning it is not possible to manipulate that content.

Comment: Even if you don't have access to iframe html before, when you load the iframe, it's obviously gonna load the html from the link and after that you can still access it.

Comment: Surely you cannot, For security reason the browers does not allow that.

Comment: Well this example works cause the domain name is the same on the root page as well as the iframe page, Take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/b2kmrqt4/ with an external url loaded on the iframe, Its does not work :D

Comment: Yeah..got you man. It won't work for external urls then. Thanks for clarifying! :)

Comment: No problem bro :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading an external url in your `iFrame`, then it is NOT Possible to manipulate or access the content of that page.

However, If the loaded url is from the same origin/domain name, You can achieve this using the example code that @TheUnKnown has provided.

Browsers restrict access to external url pages because of security reason, Other wise hackers can steal your data or manipulate them.